# How to insert a value into all cells under a column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL table there is a column named IsApproved and it's all NULL. I want to turn them to 'TRUE'. I wrote this SQL statement but it didn't work :

```
INSERT INTO [persondb].[dbo].[Person] (IsApproved) VALUES ('True')
```

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: What is datatype of IsApproved?

Comment: you need `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the table with the `true` value

```
update table [persondb].[dbo].[Person] 
set IsApproved = 'True' where IsApproved is null
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to update it not insert:

```
update [persondb].[dbo].[Person] set IsApproved ='True' -- or 1, depends on the field type 
where IsApproved  is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this following one.

select IsNull(IsApproved,'true') from tablename.

(or)

update [persondb].[dbo].[Person] set IsApproved ='True' where IsApproved  is null

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) If you only want to show It as result (not to change in table) In following:

```
SELECT ISNULL(IsApproved, 'True')
```

If you want to change It in table you should use [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

```
UPDATE TABLE [persondb].[dbo].[Person] 
SET IsApproved = 'True' 
WHERE IsApproved IS NULL
```